# spring boot post modelandview error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-post, spring-boot

I'm doing work on angularjs and spring boot .

My work request works well for `HTTP GET`s,
but I'm having problems with the `POST` request controller returning `null`

This is working:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView indexStringGet(Model model, @RequestParam(id) String orderId,
        HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println("=== get Index");//
    System.out.println("=== orderId" + orderId);

     String path = request.getContextPath();        
     System.out.println("== path" + path);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("test1");
    return mv;
}
```

but this Request method 'POST' not supported

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView indexStringPost(Model model, @RequestParam(id) String orderId,
HttpServletRequest request){
System.out.println("=== get Index");//
System.out.println("=== orderId" + orderId);

 String path = request.getContextPath();        
 System.out.println("== path" + path);
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
mv.setViewName("test1");
return mv;
}
```

this is the result:

```
"status": 405,
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
"message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
"path": "/SpringBoot/test1"
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you returning a `ModelAndView` as a `@ResponseBody`? The URL for your post is `/foodo` I guess it needs to be `/foo.do`...